# Debug Configurations java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Wow, this is a doozie.  Basically I opened Eclipse today to test an Android App that I've been working on and receive this popup error when I attempt to run the app, or edit the Debug Configurations:
"An error has occured. See error log for more details. java.lang.NullPointerException".  Any suggestions are appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the Project Properties, I was receiving this error:

```
Could not find C:\......\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe!
```

This had to do with the 2.3 SDK update. Checking for updates fixed the issue, as the new ADT plugin knows where to find apt and adb.  Problem Solved!

Answer (score 3):

You should look at Eclipse logs first. The workspace log is located in *workspace_dir*/.metadata/.log

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is run DDMS and look at the trace stack. It should show you what line the null pointer is at. Make sure there is a real value for all variables, and if you need help, post the code and line it's at, and we'll see what we can do.